# Positioning an <img> in relation to another <img> while maintaining resizability

Tags: html, css

As part of a website I'm working on for a class midterm project I'm trying to create an interactive map. The goal is to position an image in the center of the page (which I have done) which is a map of my universities north campus. Then place another image over top which is like a "marker" image. The goal is to have multiple of the these "marker" images over the map, so when you mouse over them they bring up a pop-up showing images or videos.

I'm currently stuck at maintaining the marker `<img>` where I want it in relation to the parent `<img>` when I change the width of the page. I could just hard code the size of the map image. However, I would much prefer maintaining the ability for it to resize.

HTML:

```
<div id="localmapwrapper">
    <img id="marker" src="img/point-marker.png" onmouseover="showPoint(1)"/>
    <img src="img/north-campus.jpg" width="100%" />
</div>
```

css:

```
#marker {
    width:10%;
    position: absolute;
    right:80%;
    top:50%;
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dunno. responsiveness could be tough. You should look into a pan/drag solution so you can limit the viewable area of the map. Same way maps work.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. **Your problem is not reproducible through the code you have pasted**. Be sure to create a **minimal** example with the **`HTML`** and **`CSS`** code necessary for us to see your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DIV `.localmapwrapper` needs to have `position: relative;` so that the absolute position of `#marker` has something it can relate to.